# How to format data for display in a text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a button that shows some part of the URL on a text view, but I would like for this information to be shown in a specific format.

```
- (IBAction)Accesos:(id)sender {
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray* Response_array = [json objectForKey:@"avenidas"]; 
for (int i=0; i < Response_array.count; i++){ 
NSDictionary* item = [Response_array objectAtIndex:i]; 
NSString* name = [item objectForKey:@"name"]; 
NSString* state = [item objectForKey:@"state"]; 
NSString* space = @"\n";
NSString* formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@: %@",space, name, state];  
txt_webservice_response.text = formattedString; } 
}
```

The information is shown the same as in the URL I would like to display the information like name: state and then the state to be in color depending the type if it is possible.

Comment: What, pray tell, does this have to do with JSON??  (But you need to use an NSAttributedString, assigned to the `attributedText` property, to display with multiple fonts/colors.  However, this only works on iOS 6.)

Comment: ok, the url has something like this {"avenidas":[{"name":"Alicia Moreau de Justo (Puerto","state":"Normal"} if I want the information to be display like "name: state"  for example something like this "Alicia Moreau de Justo (Puerto: Normal" how should I do it?

Comment: You want to display text with varying colors.  Whether the text is JSON or Martian makes no difference in the problem.  (Learn to eliminate the stuff that isn't part of the problem.)

Comment: ok, forget about the color, first I want to display the information in this format name:state, the color issue was something I wanted to do if it was easy, first I want the format of the information

Comment: @HotLicks with the new code I get the format but only one line is shown on the text view

Comment: You have to concatenate the lines with newline characters (`\n`) in-between, and display in a label or text view that is multi-line capable.

Comment: the newline character didn't work still getting only one line

Comment: the thing is that the nslog shows all the lines, also tried using a multi-line label but also it didn't worked

Comment: NSLog won't show it formatted.  You've got to put it into a label or text view.

Comment: @HotLicks txt_webservice_response is a text view I added the \n newline character but still showing only one line

Comment: manage to fix it by adding this line txt_webservice_response.text = [txt_webservice_response.text stringByAppendingFormat:formattedString];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray* items = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"avenidas"];
NSDictionary* item = [items objectAtIndex:someIndex];
NSString* name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString* state = [item objectForKey:@"state"];
NSString* formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", name, state];
```

(All of this is first-week stuff -- if you don't know it you need to spend more time studying the fundamentals.)

Comment: great now it's working but I am only getting only 1 line on the text view, what should I put on someIndex? I don't have a tableview for the data.

Comment: just use for loop to iterate items array and get string then append string for each iteration then display in textview

Comment: @user2259545 - What Sugan said.  And again, this is first-week stuff -- you really need to learn more of the basics before you develop too many bad habits.

Comment: I made a int i that counts till is equal to the array count but got an error data parameter is nil here is the code I use for (int i=0; i < Response_array.count; i ++) { here I put the dictionary and the strings  }

Comment: this is the code I put:     NSArray* Response_array = [json objectForKey:@"avenidas"];
    for (int i=0; i < Response_array.count; i++){
        NSDictionary* item = [Response_array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString* state = [item objectForKey:@"state"];
        NSString* formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", name, state];
        txt_webservice_response.text = formattedString;
    }

Comment: @user2259545 - Edit it into your original question, so it's formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HTML for the response and show it to webView for coloring